# Point of Inflection Inequality in a Quartic

Tags: calculus

#### The following is a multiple choice question from a workbooklet (year 12):

The family of graphs of the form $y=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx$ has two points of inflection if and only if:

A. $b<\frac{3a^2}{8}$

B. $b^2>3c$

C. $a<b$

D. $b^2<4c$

E. none of these

**Answer:** A

My question is how do I solve this? It would be great if you could show your working. Thanks in advance.

**My working**

I've done the double derivative but that's it. I'm kinda stuck.

$y=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx$

$y'=4x^3+3ax^2+2bx+c$

$y''=12x^2+6ax+2b$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Jose. Thanks for feedback. Is this ok now?

Comment: It's better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Inflection points are points where the function changes concavity, i.e. from being "concave up" to being "concave down" or vice versa. They can be found by considering where the second derivative changes signs. In similar to critical points in the first derivative, inflection points will occur when the second derivative is either zero or undefined.

$y'=4x^3 + 3ax^2 + 2bx + c$

$y'' = 12x^2+6ax+2b$

We have to solve now: $y''=0 \iff 12x^2+6ax+2b=0$.

Next, we require that the family of graphs having two inflection points, so it is necessary that the discriminant $D=(6a)^2-4\cdot12\cdot2b>0$,

i.e.

$$36a^2-96b>0 \iff b< \frac{3a^2}{8}.$$

Comment: Great. Thank-you. I knew I had to use the discriminant! Marked as answer.

Comment: You are welcome @Hugs, and thanks for mark/upvote!

Comment: your welcome Anton